# :app:mergeDebugAssets > unable to create new thread when updating to Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I was building a project with a previous version of Android Studio and I decided to update it. So once I updated it I keep getting the same error on application Run (not on clear, not on synching grandle). The error is the following:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'. > unable to create new native thread

I tried to clean and build again. I tried to change studio.vmoptions but none of them worked for me.

Here is the full build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all 
 sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: post your full gradle file

Comment: build.gradle file?

Comment: yes ofcourse ..

Comment: same problem here. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Pls update distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip in gradle-wrapper.properties file at gradle folder then rebuild your project.

Comment: The distributionUrl I have on the file is the same with the one you suggested